# Cron expression for biweekly jobs in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to look for cron expression to schedule a job every alternate Mondays at 12 PM. I am using Rundeck to schedule my jobs.

How do i create an expression that runs a job like this ?

```
1st Run => 01-July-2019 [Monday] 12:00 PM
2nd Run => 15-July-2019 [Monday] 12:00 PM
3rd Run => 29-July-2019 [Monday] 12:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another "verifier" job (using Rundeck API) that modifies the first at every alternate, here you have a good example: https://github.com/G3NSVRV/Rundeck-Scripts/tree/master/ProjectExamples/ConditionalCron (take a look from line 39 to 50 in "Cron.xml" file).